how to resolve exception while reading private key from file
i am trying to read private key from a file using the below code and getting an exception.  is there any way to resolve it?
generatePrivate() method throws invalidkeyspecexception.
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;

(...)
try {
             
    Path path = Paths.get(THE_BINARY_ENCODED_FILE_PATH);
    byte[] privKeyByteArray = Files.readAllBytes(path);
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privKeyByteArray);
    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey privateKey= keyFactory.generatePrivate(keySpec);
    
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}



how to solvethis?

look in the documentation what causes that Exception to be thrown

You can't share the file you're reading for obvious reasons, so please check whether the first answer here (the last part, in particular) helps.

When java tells you: "This key file is invalid" then.. the key file is invalid. We can't help you; ordinarily we'd say: Share the key file, we'll have a look, but, you obviously wouldn't want to share this. Can you repeat the process that made this key, make a new one, and post that?

PKCS8EncodedKeySpec() requires a DER encoded key in PKCS#8 format. Check if this applies to your key.

Don't use images for text information like code or logs. Share the exception with stacktrace as text.

If I were to take a wild guess, I'd guess your private key is in PEM format rather than binary DER. That won't work.

yes my key is in pem format.

My key was invalid. tried with different file and it worked!
